# check if user registered on the required website

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

i am currently developing a website where user needs to signup on particular websites to get some points.user will register on that website and then enter his user-name and email in our site to tell that he registered on that website with following details and got this user-name. But the problem i am facing is that, as we know we can't directly access another domain's database. So I am currently facing problem to find a method by which i could check if user signed up on that website or not. 
please suggest me something by which i can check the genuineness of user's claim of signing up on that website. (I am developing this website using CodeIgniter 3.x)

Comment: You need to use api call for those site or provide api access to those vendor so they can pre check signup from your site.

Comment: how this will be done.please explain.

Comment: Like fb api they provide some api for get user authentication by entering email and password from other site use this link for more info https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api

and FB api takes those paramter and process that on his server and they identify this user is exist or not based on that they will server response in success or failuer.

so you need to do same for allow some other to check this user is exist in your site.

Comment: okay! seems possible. I will try to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same idea with @Niketan, but (worst method if target website doesn't provide any api) if the target website's registration page doesn't require captcha (or any other anti-bot techniques), you can use curl to submit the form and get the result back.

Comment: please explain this in detail as I am a newbie.

Comment: Could not make an example code for you at the moment. But the think is:
- Worst method1: If the target websites is a public website, and user has own page on it like facebook (E.g. fb.com/markzuckerberg). Using curl to make a request to user's page and see if it's existing.
- Worst method 2: Example if you're trying to register with an existing username, you will get back an error message (e.g. already registered). By use curl to submit the registration form (with the username) you can get back the result after parsing the html and find the message.

Comment: But as I said before, they are worst methods in case you don't have any other ways to access their data. The best solution for this case is ask the target website for some APIs and you can check by make some request to their APIs.

Comment: could you provide any alternate way in which we don't have to access another website. any method..